# How can I make git status be quiet when updating to a certain changeset?

Tags: git

Let's say I commit 5 changesets, and I want to update to the 3rd:

```
git checkout 3rd sha .
```

After I do the checkout, I'm in the exact state I was at the 3rd revision. So, I want to make it so that if I run `git status` it will only show me things that changed in respect to that changeset. I don't want git status to use HEAD as it's reference. I would like behavious similar to mercurial's. Is this possible? Is this possible without checking out that revision to a new branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `git reset <3rd sha>` and do `git diff`, `git status` etc.

To go back to original head, use `git reset HEAD@{1}` or `git reflog` and find the appropriate sha and reset to it

Comment: Shouldn't the reset be with `--hard`, in order for `git status` to be quiet?

Comment: @Senthess - what do you mean quiet? You are saying you want to see changes? If you do with `--hard` you will lose changes.

Comment: when I update to the changeset, I only want to see things that are different related to that changeset.